# Is it safe to change HTML 5 Boilerplate default font size?

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate

I think the default font size for HTML5 Boilerplate is a little high for my tastes in the website I'm designing but I love the features it has. Would it be safe to change the `font-size:1em;` in main.css to something like `font-size:0.9em;`?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely - it's just CSS. It's there to make look like you want it too.

[In fact bumping up the size might not be a bad idea](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/16-pixels-body-copy-anything-less-costly-mistake/)